# How to deal with NAN warning message in poweRlaw package in R?

Tags: r, nan, power-law

I am using poweRlaw package to fit distribution as described by Gillespie , but I got this warning messages which is given in attach and I am blocked can't go on?

What should I do for continuing with the procedure?

How to deal with NAN warning message in poweRlaw package in R?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The language tag was missing. Apart from that, you have chosen the "power-law" tag, but based on its description ("A power law is a functional relationship between two quantities, where one quantity varies as a power of another") I don't think it's what you mean. What you mean is a package, so I think the tag is wrong and should be removed, however I am not sure. Could you please check and, in case, edit the question? Thank you!

Comment: The `power-law` tag is correct here, I think, as the `poweRlaw` package is indeed designed to fit model relationships in data. To make answering this question slightly easier, could the author produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have numerical instability. This usually means that the lognormal isn't suitbale. However, without a reproducible example it's not possible to tell. Create an issue at https://github.com/csgillespie/powerlaw with a data set that can be used to reproduce the problem.